# Why did Fontane choose to write "The Tragedy of Afghanistan"?

Tags: poetry, inspiration, german-language, theodor-fontane

Theodor Fontane, a German poet, wrote "Das Trauerspiel von Afghanistan" (translated [here](http://berlinbooks.org/brb/2010/01/the-tragedy-of-afghanistan/) as "The Tragedy of Afghanistan") in 1847. It's about the aftermath of a massacre suffered by a British force in 1842. The poem is certainly a good read, and the historical event certainty compelling. **What I'm unsure of is why Fontane chose to write about this event specifically.** Why was he drawn to highlight a old-ish incident concerning the British army, as opposed to something closer to home? Is there something about the whole affair that drew Fontane to compose his poem? I would appreciate answers that have evidence directly from Fontane, or other sources which could be absolutely sure, but well-backed up speculation would be fine as well.

Why did Fontane choose to write "The Tragedy of Afghanistan"?

Comment: Germany didn't exist in 1847 (although German definitely did).  In 1847, Fontane was a Prussian poet.

Comment: @PeterShor The name "Deutschland" was already in use in 1847 and Prussia was part of the [Deutscher Bund](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutscher_Bund). As far as I know, it's perfectly normal to describe Fontane as a German author instead of a Prussian author.

Comment: And Goethe was a Roman author? ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theodor Fontane did not write "Das Trauerspiel von Afghanistan" in 1847/8, as the [Berlin Review of Books](http://berlinbooks.org/brb/2010/01/the-tragedy-of-afghanistan/) erroneously claims, but a decade later.
By that time, Fontane had been twice been **in London as a foreign correspondent** for Prussian newspapers: the first time from April till September 1852 (Bemmann: 99-106) and the second time from September 1855 till January 1859. The occasion for the second time was the [**Crimean War**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crimean_War), in which Prussia did not want to intervene (Bemmann: 113–131).
(Fontane had developed an interest in England in the 1840s, reading, for example, [Hume's massive *History of England*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_History_of_England_(Hume)) and the works of Walter Scott. England and Scotland had been important sources of inspiration for his ballads.)

By the end of his second stay in England, his **admiration for the British people was at its nadir**. He described the English as a "money-making Volk" and was especially appalled by the massacres during the [Indian Rebellion of 1857–1858](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Rebellion_of_1857). In a letter to the editor-in-chief of the *Neue Preußische (Kreuz-)Zeitung* (his employer), he wrote that, with regard to India, all of England disgusted him; he even described the English as a people of "robbers and pirates". (In spite of his criticism of English colonialism and English society, he did not condemn the English people as a whole.)

It is perhaps this historical background and his criticism of colonialism that inpired him to write "Das Trauerspiel von Afghanistan". (I have been unable to find statements about a specific explicit motivation to write this poem.) According to the entries in his diary, he worked on the poem on 1 and 2 May **1858**; he recited the poem for the literary society [Tunnel über der Spree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunnel_%C3%BCber_der_Spree) (in Berlin) on 3 April 1859. It was printed in the magazine *Argo* in 1860 (*Tagebücher*: 616). Before April 1859, Fontane had already recited the poem in London on 5 August 1858 (Berbig: Theodor Fontane Chronik: 905) and for the literary society "Krokodillen-Gesellschaft" in Munich on 10 March 1859 (Berbig: Theodor Fontane Chronik: 962).

---

Sources:

- Bemmann, Helga: *Theodor Fontane. Eine preußischer Dichter*. Ullstein, 1998. (440-page biography published on the occasion of the 100th anniversary of the author's death; now out of print.)
- Berbig, Roland: [*Theodor Fontane Chronik*](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/9783110215601/html). De Gruyter, 2010. (Day-by-day chronicle of Fontane's life and works, based on the author's correspondence and diaries, and other sources; 3.905 pages.)
- Fontane, Theodor: *Tage- und Reisetagebücher: Tagebücher 1852, 1855-1858*. Edited by Charlotte Jolles, Rudolf Muhs, Gotthard Erler and Therese Erler. Aufbau-Verlag, 1995.

Comment: Let me add that if Fontane was looking to write about an example of a disastrous military defeat, I think he would have been very hard-pressed to find any other recent comparable examples. This was really an unparalleled event.

Comment: @PeterShor I think you're right. He also wrote a free translation of Tennyson's "Charge of the Light Brigade", but the perception of that event is very different.